# Customize dialog which has single-choice list items

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I created a **Dialog** with single-choice list items:

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Colors");
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

How can I customize the layout of this dialog so that each list item in the dialog consists of a icon and a text. How to create custom layout for the list on the dialog?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Steps for Creating customize dialog:

1. Create the dialog box layout files, like:

   ```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
   android:layout_height = "wrap_content">
   <!-- The Title Bar -->
   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/dlg_priority_titlebar"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

       <ImageView
           android:src="@drawable/image"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_margin="5dip" />

       <TextView
           android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
               android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
               android:text = "Select Task Priority"
               android:layout_gravity = "center_vertical" />
   </LinearLayout>
   <ListView 
       android:id="@+id/dlg_priority_lvw"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/dlg_priority_titlebar"
       android:background="@drawable/layout_home_bg">
   </ListView>
   ```
2. Because the layout in the `ListView` custom, so to create a layout file for the `ListView`:

   ```
   <LinearLayout xmlns: android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
       android:orientation = "horizontal" 
       android:layout_width = "fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height = "fill_parent"> 

   <ImageView 
         android:id = "@+id/list_priority_img" 
         android:layout_width = "wrap_content" 
         android:layout_height = "wrap_content" 
         android:layout_gravity = "center_vertical" 
         android:layout_margin = "5dip" /> 
   <TextView 
        android:id = "@+id/list_priority_value" 
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height = "wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity = "center_vertical" 
        android:textsize = "28dip" 
        android:textColor = "@drawable/ black" /> 
   </LinearLayout>
   ```
3. Create a custom `Dialog` class `PriorityDlg` inherited from `Dialog`

   ```
        public class PriorityDlg extends Dialog {

       private Context context;
       private ListView dlg_priority_lvw = null;
       public PriorityDlg(Context context) {
           super(context);
           this.context = context;
           // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
       }
       public PriorityDlg(Context context, int theme) {
           super(context, theme);
           this.context = context;
       }
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           this.setContentView(R.layout.dlg_priority);
           dlg_priority_lvw = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.dlg_priority_lvw);
           // ListView
           SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, getPriorityList(),
                   R.layout.lvw_priority, new String[] { "list_priority_img",
                           "list_priority_value" }, new int[] {
                           R.id.list_priority_img, R.id.list_priority_value });
           dlg_priority_lvw.setAdapter(adapter);
           //ListView
           dlg_priority_lvw
                   .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                       @Override
                       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                               int arg2, long arg3) {

                       }
                   });
       }
       private List<HashMap<String, Object>> getPriorityList() {
           List<HashMap<String, Object>> priorityList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
           HashMap<String, Object> map1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
           map1.put("list_priority_img", R.drawable.priority_not_important);
           map1.put("list_priority_value", context.getResources().getString(
                   R.string.dlg_priority_not_important));
           priorityList.add(map1);
           HashMap<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
           map2.put("list_priority_img", R.drawable.priority_general);
           map2.put("list_priority_value", context.getResources().getString(
                   R.string.dlg_priority_general));
           priorityList.add(map2);
           HashMap<String, Object> map3 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
           map3.put("list_priority_img", R.drawable.priority_important);
           map3.put("list_priority_value", context.getResources().getString(
                   R.string.dlg_priority_important));
           priorityList.add(map3);
           HashMap<String, Object> map4 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
           map4.put("list_priority_img", R.drawable.priority_very_important);
           map4.put("list_priority_value", context.getResources().getString(
                   R.string.dlg_priority_very_important));
           priorityList.add(map4);

           return priorityList;
       }

   }
   ```
4. To create a custom dialog box

   ```
   PriorityDlg dlg = new PriorityDlg (SimpleTaskActivity.this, R.style.dlg_priority); 
   dlg.show();
   ```

Where `R.style.dlg_priority` set the dialog box uses the style file, just let the dialog box to remove the title bar, and of course you can code to complete this effect:

```
<? Xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?> 
<resources> 
    <style name="dlg_priority" parent="@android:Theme.Dialog"> 
        <item name = "android: windowNoTitle"> true </ item> 
    </ style> 
</ resources>
```

Comment: I will try your code out this weekend, and let you know , thank you

Answer (score 4):

You basically will have to create your own `ListAdapter` by
subclassing one of the available Adapter classes and supply that to
the dialog (using `builder.setAdapter(...)`). If you have an array or
list of items/objects, subclassing `ArrayAdapter` is probably what
you'll want to look into.

In your Adapter subclass, you override the `getView(...)` method (amongst others) and fill the views of your custom layout with data
for the supplied position in the list. More specifically, you'll want
to set an image against an `ImageView` and text to a `TextView`.

> ```
>  Create class `MySimpleArrayAdapter` extending from  `ArrayAdapter`.
> ```

Using `ListView.setOnItemClickListener()` method we get selected value of `CheckTextView`

> ```
> #dialog.xml
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:background="@color/whitebox_bg"
>     android:orientation="horizontal" >
>
>         <CheckedTextView
>             android:id="@+id/textDialog"
>             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
>             android:gravity="center_vertical"
>             android:maxLines="10"
>             android:singleLine="false"
>             android:text=""
>             android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
>             android:textColor="#000000" />
>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

To create a custom dialog box

> ```
>         String [] view_location = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};
>               TextView label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selected_dept);
>               AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
>               builder.setTitle("Select Location");
>               ListView listview = new ListView(this);
>               listview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
>                       LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
>               listview.setCacheColorHint(0);
>               listview.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
>
>
>               if (view_location != null) {
>
>                   MySimpleArrayAdapter choice_arrayAdapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(this, view_location,label.getText().toString());
>                   listview.setAdapter(choice_arrayAdapter);
>                   builder.setView(listview);
>
>                   listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
>                       @Override
>                       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
>                               int arg2, long arg3) {
>                           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>                           TextView label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selected_dept);
>                           label.setText(view_location[arg2]);
>                           survedObjectId = view_location_id[arg2];
>                           dInterface.dismiss();
>
>                       }
>                   });
>
>
>               }
>               Dialog dialog = builder.create();
>               dInterface = dialog;
>               dialog.getWindow().setLayout(200, 400);
>               dialog.show();'
>
>     // `Extends From ArrayAdapter
>
>      'public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
>              private final Context context;
>              private final String[] values;
>              private final String  selectedText;
>              public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values, String  selectedText) {
>                super(context, R.layout.dialog_text, values);
>                this.context = context;
>                this.values = values;
>                this.selectedText = selectedText;
>              }
>
>              @Override
>              public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
>                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
>                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
>                View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_text, parent, false);
>                CheckedTextView textView = (CheckedTextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textDialog);
>
>                textView.setText(values[position]);
>                if(textView.getText().toString().equals(selectedText))
>                {
>                  textView.setChecked(true);
>                }
>                else
>                {
>                  textView.setChecked(false);
>                }
>
>                return rowView;
>              }
>            }'
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You basically will have to create your own ListAdapter by subclassing one of the available Adapter classes and supply that to the dialog (using [`builder.setAdapter(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setAdapter%28android.widget.ListAdapter,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener%29)). If you have an array or list of items/objects, subclassing ArrayAdapter is probably what you'll want to look into.

In your Adapter subclass, you override the `getView(...)` method (amongst others) and fill the views of your custom layout with data for the supplied position in the list. More specifically, you'll want to set an image against an ImageView and text to a TextView.

A fairly nice tutorial that demonstrates how to implement a custom ArrayAdapter, and happens to be close to what you're trying to accomplish, can be found [here](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429&q=customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter). It also shows how to use the ViewHolder/RowWrapper concept.