# Changing the color of a currently selected item in an Android alert-dialog

Tags: java, android, user-interface, dialog

I'm creating a dialog in Android with a custom style:

```java
new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.CustomAlertDialog))
    .setSingleChoiceItems(keys, selectedIndex,
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
          @Override
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int index) {
            // ...
            dialog.dismiss();
          }
        })
    .create()
    .show();
```

where `CustomAlertDialog` looks like this:

```xml
<style name="CustomAlertDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">

  <!--
  <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
  <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
  -->
</style>
```

This works fine (if I uncomment the `typeface` and `textSize`, I see the changes). However, I would also like to change the light-blue color of the currently selected item into something else:

[image]

Is this possible through my `CustomAlertDialog`? If so, how?

Comment: maybe here you can find a solution [Customize dialog which has single-choice list items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839395/customize-dialog-which-has-single-choice-list-items)

Comment: Is there a requirement that you need to modify the views via STYLE as opposed to inflating a custom layout for each list item within the list via list adapter?

Comment: @anudroid, well, the requirement being: doing as less coding myself as possible. Sure I can create my own layout but I'd rather use Android's built-in dialogs (and style them). Given the lack of answers to this question, I'll probably resort to doing this myself.

Comment: @BartKiers what API levels are you targeting?

Comment: @EvelioTarazona, Android version 2.2+.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright here is a quick answer, I might improve it later regarding API Level 8+

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhErc.png]

For API Level 11+

It is easy they added `alertDialogTheme` and `textColorAlertDialogListItem` and just work:

```java
new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.CustomAlertDialog))
  .setSingleChoiceItems(new String[] {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four"}, 2,
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int index) {
        // ...
        dialog.dismiss();
      }
    })
  .create()
  .show();
```

`styles.xml`

```
<style name="CustomAlertDialog">
  <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/CustomAlertDialogTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomAlertDialogTheme">
  <item name="android:textColorAlertDialogListItem">@color/some_colors</item>
</style>
```

`some_colors.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/my_dialog_checked"/>
  <item android:color="@color/my_dialog_default"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

For API Level 8+

I think the "safest" way to go as mentioned before is implementing your own item layout as you will have total control over your items appearance this is mainly because in old versions of the platform they had "hard coded" colors and styles on those layouts.

You could also play without `Builder` and use `AlertDialog/Dialog(Context context, int theme)` directly but I am a bit short of time at this point and I didn't want to invest much time on this right now.

Comment: Too bad it doesn't work for API 8, but thanks for your answer nevertheless!

Answer (score 0):

```
 <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/checkbox_active" />
```

Should handle any pressed radio button.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but placing this inside the `<style> ... </style>` of my `CustomAlertDialog`-style does not work. Where did you think I'd place this? Note  that I'm not directly working with a radio button, but rather with an `AlertDialog`.

Comment: Hm. You're right and upon looking for it myself, it doesn't seem documented any where online. Have you tried using CTRL-SPACE to auto-complete with what you think it might be?

Comment: yeah, tried all sorts of `<item name="android:...Color...">` variations in my `CustomAlertDialog`-style, none of which work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I havent tried this, this seems to exist in the Theme.Holo docs, might be in Theme.Dialog, but you could try adding this

```
<item name="colorPressedHighlight">@color/yourcolour</item>
<item name="colorLongPressedHighlight">@color/yourcolour2</item>
```